AWS EventBridge Pipeline - Self Managed Kafka filter not working
I have event coming from self-managed kafka in following format:
{
  "topic":"aaa",
  "partition":16,
  "offset":108687,
  "timestamp":1721654305109,
  "timestampType":"CREATE_TIME",
  "key":"MzM4NjU5ODAwOA==",
  "value":"eyJldmVudElkIjoiMzA4NjMwZGQtMzFmZi00OWQ0LWI4YTEtNGU1NzBiOGE0YTQwIiwiZXZlbnRUeXBlIjoiT1JERVJfUkVBRFlfRk9SX0ZVTEZJTExNRU5UIiwiZXZlbnREYXRlIjoiMjAyNC0wNy0yMlQxMzoxODoyNC42MzNaIn0=",
  "headers":[]},
  "bootstrapServers":"aaa",
  "eventSource":
  "SelfManagedKafka",
  "eventSourceKey":"aaa"
}

And filter:
{
  "value.detailType":["ORDER_READY_FOR_FULFILLMENT"]
}

The filter is not passing my event and I receive none. What can be an issue here?

Since your base64-encoded JSON object in value is:
{
  "eventId": "308630dd-31ff-49d4-b8a1-4e570b8a4a40",
  "eventType": "ORDER_READY_FOR_FULFILLMENT",
  "eventDate": "2024-07-22T13:18:24.633Z"
}

the filter criteria should be:
  {
    "value": {
       "eventType": ["ORDER_READY_FOR_FULFILLMENT"]
    }
  }

(typing this from mobile phone without validation, so please play with it.
Please also see Pipes filtering for details.
